# laravel4 update additional columns in pivot table

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to update additional column data in a pivot table in a many to many relationship.

I have two tables - reservation and resource linked with a pivot table. I can attach and am working with the model. However I'm struggling to update one of the additional columns in the pivot table.

I have an object: '$reservation' From that object I created another object $resources using:

```
$resources = $reservation->resource()->get();
```

I'm then iterating through `$resources` using a `foreach` loop as follows

```
foreach($resources as $resource ) {...}
```

I then want to update a column called gcal_id and am using the following:

```
$resource->pivot->gcal_id = "TEST";
$resource->save();
```

If I var_dump the model I can see the property exists to the correct value but in the database itself the entry is not being updated - so the save is not working

I have the columns listed in both sides of the relationship with this:

```
->withPivot('start', 'end', 'quantity', 'product_id','gcal_id')
```

Given I have the resource object how can I update a column correctly in the pivot table and save to database?

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After that you set the attribute on the pivot:

```
$resource->pivot->gcal_id = "TEST";
```

You seem to save the *resource* and not the pivot:

```
$resource->save();
```

If you want the pivot to be saved, saving the resource is not enough. Call save on the *pivot* instead:

```
$resource->pivot->gcal_id = "TEST";
$resource->pivot->save();
```

Comment: Thank you. I still havent quite got the relationships in my head. I struggle getting the methods right. Your solution worked - must remember to consider what model I'm manipulating

Answer (score 4):

An alternative instead of `save` method, is the method `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany\updateExistingPivot()`

```
$reservation->resource()->updateExistingPivot($resource_id, ['gcal_id' => 'TEST']);
```

Or

```
$reservation->resource()->updateExistingPivot([1, 4, 5, 6], ['gcal_id' => 'TEST']);
```

This work for me in `Laravel 4.2`