# Laravel 4 - save order in pivot table

Tags: laravel-4, pivot-table

I have two tables `actividads`and `fichas`... and a pivot table `actividad_ficha`. I have created another column in my pivot table: `orden_actividad` where I would like to save the order of the 'activities' in every 'ficha'.

My main problem is that I have no idea how to create an order in my pivot table. I mean, for example, `ficha 4` is related in my pivot table with `actividad 1`, `actividad 6` and `actividad 9`, and I want to create the order of the activities:

```
ficha - actividad - orden_actividad
  4         1            1
  4         6            2
  4         9            3
```

My purpose is, after that, order the activities by 'orden_actividad' and allow the user to reorder them.

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Possibly related to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19083779/laravel4-update-additional-columns-in-pivot-table

Answer (score 0):

You can add values to custom columns in your pivot table like this:

```
$actividad_id = /* fetch $actividad_id here */;

$orden_actividad = $ficha->actividad->count() + 1;

$ficha->actividad()->attach($actividad_id, array('orden_actividad', $orden_actividad));
```