# UpdateExistingPivot for multiple ids

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

In order to update single record in pivot table I use `updateExistingPivot` method. However it takes $id as the first argument. For example:

```
$step->contacts()->updateExistingPivot($id, [
    'completed' => true,
    'run_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString()
]);
```

But how can I update multiple existing rows in pivot table at once?

Comment: Not sure, but try to put there an array with ids

Comment: I tried and it didn't work :(

Comment: Maybe it is a bug, it seems to be work http://stackoverflow.com/a/30756967/4581725

Comment: But that is just link for an old Laravel version. It does not work like that on Laravel 5.

Answer (score 15):

There's an allRelatedIds() method in the BelongsToMany relation that you can access, which will return a Collection of the related model's ids that appear in the pivot table against the initial model.

Then a foreach will do the job:

```
$ids = $step->contacts()->allRelatedIds();

foreach ($ids as $id){
    $step->contacts()->updateExistingPivot($id, ['completed' => true]);
}
```

Comment: FYI, the method is now named `allRelatedIds`.

Comment: Old answer, but still relevant... you can pass an array of IDs as a first parameter, so `$step->contacts()->updateExistingPivot($step->contacts()->allRelatedIds()...` would work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can update only by using a looping statement as there updateExistingPivot function only accept one dimensional params, See the core function for laravel 5.3.

```
File: yoursite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany.php
```

Function: updateExistingPivot

```
public function updateExistingPivot($id, array $attributes, $touch = true)
    {
        if (in_array($this->updatedAt(), $this->pivotColumns)) {
            $attributes = $this->setTimestampsOnAttach($attributes, true);
        }

        $updated = $this->newPivotStatementForId($id)->update($attributes);

        if ($touch) {
            $this->touchIfTouching();
        }

        return $updated;
    }
```

So, You should follow the simple process:

```
$step = Step::find($stepId);
foreach(yourDataList as $youData){
   $step->contacts()->updateExistingPivot($youData->contract_id, [
    'completed' => true,
    'run_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString()
]);

}
```