# UpdateExistingPivot for multiple ids in loop = n+1 problem. Is there another way?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

There's [another very similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36694081/updateexistingpivot-for-multiple-ids) with an answer that was very helpful (and I'm currently using) but causes the n+1 query problem.

I'll outline my use case. Polymorphic many to many relationship
I have:

1. Location model
2. Vendor model
3. User Model
4. Contactable (custom pivot model - still fleshing this out)

Users can be marked as contacts (aka contactables) for both Locations and Vendors.
I need to *not* detach contactables when dissociating them (I need a record of the fact that a User was once a contact for a location or vendor) so I don't want to detach them, I need to mark them inactive. 
I'll limit the scope of this scenario to the following fields in the contactables table:

1. active
2. user_ID
3. contactable_type
4. contactable_ID

So I'm executing:

```
    $collectionOfLocationIds = $contactDetails->locations()->getRelatedIds(); //changed to 'allRelatedIds()' in 5.4+

    foreach ($collectionOfLocationIds as $locationID)
     {
       $contactDetails->locations()->updateExistingPivot($locationID, ['active' => 0]);
     }
```

This runs great for most of my vendors, but some have 5k+ locations, so then I'm executing 5k+ update operations for what should really be one query. DB lives on a different server, so a few extra milliseconds add up pretty quickly...

I tried passing an array of ids to the updateExistingPivot function ([it says it will take a mixed type for the id parameter](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.html#method_updateExistingPivot)) it doesn't produce an error, but it only seems to update the first id in the array. I'm not sure if this is a new bug, @[Wallace Maxters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19083779/laravel4-update-additional-columns-in-pivot-table/30756967#30756967) mentioned that he could pass an array in 4.2, and I am still working in 5.3, but I'm wondering if anyone else has had this problem.

(Updated for clarity)

Comment: Laravel 5.7.11 added support for arrays to `updateExistingPivot()`: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/26167

Answer (score 1):

Use `raw query` instead of `relationship`.

I don't exactly understand which rows you want to inactive.
So lets think you want to inactive contactable for a particualar `user`.
If its not, change it to whatever `where()`.

```
DB::table('contactable')->where('user_id', $user_id)
    ->update(['active' => 0]);
```

this will only execute one query.

Comment: Thanks for the idea - using a raw query may be the most practical way to solve my problem. Unfortunately the query you posted doesn't really solve my n+1 problem on a polymorphic relationship. I need to pass in an array of ID's (in my case, an array of location ID's). 

Something more like:

         `DB::table('contactable')->where('contactable_type', 'App\Models\Location')->whereIn('contactable_ID', $arryaOfLocation_IDs)->update(['active' => 0]);`

What I'd *really* like is an eloquent way of doing this.